# Android limit localizations

Tags: android, localization

I am trying to publish an app that is currently only configured for English. When I upload my app to the Play store, it says localization for 'Default + 49 languages'? How do I disable all but English?

Comment: Also, I only have the default values folder, no -fr, -it etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish your app, **if you wrote it only in English it will be published only in English.**

If you want to limit your app to specific countries you can do this: On the developer console you have a tab of "PRICING AND DISTRIBUTION". You can choose the countries there. Here how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can I sell my app to all countries, but have the market filter to only install for English devices? The thing that confused me was when I go to APK->Show Details, the Localizations field is given as Default + 49 languages. I plan on adding translations eventually, but I want to make sure no one downloads on accident thinking there is a translation for their language.

Comment: Maybe you should add a check for the local language: String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName(); and if you see that it is not english add a dialog that says that the app will be translated later

Comment: That's basically what I'm planning if I can't find a cleaner solution. I was just thinking that there is likely something like <compatible-screens> except for languages that I could declare in the manifest, project properties, etc. I'm guessing that you have not heard of such a functionality?

Comment: I didn't hear about this feature. If you find something let me know.

Comment: Yeah me either. Will update if I find out anything. Current plan is just to warn users on startup if their language is not supported. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I've just noticed the same issue and after some investigation found the explanation. Thought I share this in addition to the already existing answer about the consequences:

As soon as your app includes a **library that does support additional languages** (e.g. the Google Play Services), your created apk is marked to support all those localizations as well!

You can check the properties of an apk by the way even without uploading it to the Google Play Store. Just run the following from the latest **build-tools folder** inside your Android Apk. For me this is at the moment cd ~ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/19.0.1

`./aapt d badging <apk>`

As it was suggested before, it is mostly important in which languages your app description is provided cause this is what the users actually see. In addition one can include the list of real supported languages in this description.

If you really would want to get rid of the additional languages you would need to delete the language specific res-folders from all libraries. In case of local copies of the libraries this is easy. I guess using gradle and maven it should be possible as well, but I don't consider it worth doing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the issue is that if you include a library that supports other languages, all of those translations get pulled into your app and then the store assumes that you support those languages.

To stop the build tools from pulling in the unsupported languages, you can set filters on the 'aapt' packaging tool so that it will ignore particular files/directories.

The formatting for the filter can be found in the [main ant 'build.xml' file in the sdk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/98b631c6b3765be96b3707ba7aa54d52b10f4872/files/ant/build.xml). (search for `aapt.ignore.assets`)

---

The **default exclude list** is:

```
!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~
```

I'd recommend that you keep this list and append any extra filter to the end of it.

e.g. If you wanted to exclude `es-US` (which is stored in directories with the extension `-es-rUS`) you would change the exclude list to:

```
!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~:<dir>*-es-rUS
```

This will exclude all directories ending in `-es-rUS` (note that the filters are case-insensitive, so `<dir>*-eS-RuS` would work just as well)

---

To do this for the **command line**:

```
aapt.exe <All of your normal commands for packaging>  --ignore-assets <exclude-list>
```

For **Ant/Eclipse** builds add the following to your project's `ant.properties` file:

```
aapt.ignore.assets=<exclude-list>
```